# Past Simple and Present Perfect in AmE

Tags: grammar

Usually, speaking about an action that happened in the past and has a connection to the present time, we use *Present Perfect* tense. This is relevant to *British English*.

Though the question is, can we use both *Past Simple* and *Present Perfect* tenses in *American English*? If not in any case, then where should we use each tense?

For instance,

> I missed the bus, so I’m going to be late for the meeting.  -- I *think* is acceptable ***only in AmE***

> I've missed the bus, so I’m going to be late for the meeting. -- I *think* is acceptable in ***both AmE and BrE***

I appreciate your help.

-Added after reading the comment-

I'm told that for some sentences this is true, but for some - this isn't. In which cases I ought to use Past Simple tense if dealing with AmE?

Comment: What is your question? Your source says that both sentences are acceptable in AmE. So this is an example where you can use either past simple and present perfect in AmE. So the answer to your question is "yes", you can use either of them in this particular sentence. This is not true for all sentences.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've forgotten to make a statement that this was only my thoughts, not any source. And, I've also added a more direct question.

Comment: A quick answer for what to do in practice: If you treat simple past and present perfect the same way in AmE that you do in BrE, probably most people won't even notice that you're using slightly British grammar. The main difference with respect to the present perfect between BrE and AmE is that there are situations where the present perfect is used in BrE, and is optional in AmE.